# Mobile apps email verification take user to webpage not in app?

Tags: android, mobile, web-applications, email, email-validation

How are you guys doing email verification in your mobile apps? I noticed that the link will take the user to the webpage and realized this isn’t the desired outcome. I’d rather they be taken into the app and from their have their email address verified so that afterward they are still in the app instead of in the mobile website.

Comment: Usually this is right in most cases because it sends a URL to user to verify email?  I have integrated firebase in my app and verification happens in browser.To open your app you need to use deep linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here, it might help: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

It says :

> Android App Links are a special type of deep link that allow your
>   website URLs to immediately open the corresponding content in your
>   Android app (without requiring the user to select the app).